# How can I specify that the elements of an array can only be numbers between 1 and 6?

Tags: typescript

Given the following function

```
function rollDice(): 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1) as 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
}
```

And whose results will be stored in an array

```
const dataset: number[] = [];
```

How can I specify that the dataset variable will stores only values between 1 and 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the union type as the array element type:

```
type DiceNumber = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
const dataset: DiceNumber[] = [];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Fg0HUiVj8D0Ii8ACIAKKrBiIGr6ItJHFF8AOVAAcmEDMgEiLQRUAHlvmRdlr+OnjrayApXNI8KAnFGdKMsPoUAhEDDhFdExJo9ERAYODjuiw2FxuEESkA).